# Documentation tools for authoring user manual

Tags: windows, desktop-publishing

I have been asked to create a user manual for our product. I would like to create one packed with tips, tricks and warnings - using the format that one would find in the [*For Dummies* series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Dummies).

**Requirements:**

- output formats should include `.doc`, `.docx`, `.pdf`, `.html`, and `.chm` as well as `.epub` or any open standard format for eBook readers.

What author tools/packages are available for this purpose?

Comment: What OS, What Output Formats, What Readers?

Comment: I will develop on a Win7 box. For our customers, the preferred format would be  .doc, .docx, .pdf, html, chm. For our customers preferring to use eReaders, .epub or any open standard format would be quite fine. Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, Raj! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically, your post should include a (bullet-) list of requirements (must-haves and maybe nice-to-haves). E.g. what *formattings* must be supported (apart from the "basics" like italics/bold types – e.g. boxes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using markdown to write the documentation, *(and preferably .png for any screenshots, illustrations, etc.)*, and [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to output the required format(s).  BTW I would **strongly** suggest using .pdf or such for your windows customers so that they don't have to buy MS-Word if they don't already have it.

[pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is a free tool that will read a large number of input formats and output an even larger selection.

- Free
- Cross Platform
- Input formats: docbook, haddock, html, json, latex, markdown, markdown_github, markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki, opml, rst, textile
- Output formats: asciidoc, beamer, context, docbook, docx, dzslides, epub, epub3, fb2, html, html5, json, latex, man, markdown, markdown_github, markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki, native, odt, opendocument, opml, org, pdf*, plain, revealjs, rst, rtf, s5, slideous, slidy, texinfo, textile

Using a plain text format such as markdown or rst allows your user guide to go under revision control, with the source code of the project possibly, unlike binary formats.

Using output formats that are:

1. Read Only
2. Have free reader tools
3. Can be used on various platforms

Is always a good idea and following the same sort of version control that, hopefully, the developers are using will allow you to maintain different versions for different builds and versions of the product.

You should also be able to make the production of the appropriate version of the documentation a part of the build & distribution process.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. It appears there are several versions of markdown. I simply will need to choose one of them. Pandoc seems to have versatile rendering capabilities. Do you have a second recommendation to make?

Comment: @Raj - I would suggest reading up on the pandoc extended markup - http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pandocs-markdown

Comment: Many thanks to Steve's suggestion, I was able to create the user guide of our product with pandoc and most importantly, in "For Dummies" style. It was a lifesaver. Thank you Steve.

Answer (score 1):

[GitBook](https://github.com/GitbookIO/editor)

It's a GUI editor for Markdown, using [Calibre](http://www.calibre-ebook.com/) for final rendering. It allows you to have the manual with a Git and to write in separate chapters.

It's free and open source. It renders to HTML, PDF and EPUB but you can later do the conversion using other tools.